# Why Highcharts gets different size on Safari?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, safari

I have a static page with a few Highcharts instances.

Everything is great on Chrome, Firefox and IE. But if I open the page on Safari I get some of those charts with a slight different size, which is making their X axis' labels to be truncated (I'll show screenshot). In other charts I have a centered aligned data label inside the column serie, but in Safari it also gets misaligned.

Any idea why or how to fix it?

[Chart #1: Left is Chrome, Right is Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeIdq.png)

[Chart #2: Left is Chrome, Right is Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMvRn.png)

Comment: Which Safari version do you use? To prevent ellipsis on axis labels you can set `textOverflow` to 'none' in xAxis.labels.style object (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.style). Provide me with working JSFiddle demos where this problem occurs.

Comment: The Safari's version is 10.1.12. I'll try to set `textOverflow` and see how it looks like and I'll also provide a JSFiddle

Comment: There's a typo. I meant 10.1.2

Comment: Any help? Why is smaller in safari?