# Highcharts having margins issue in Safari

Tags: javascript, highcharts, safari

I've asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699767/why-highcharts-gets-different-size-on-safari) and the I realized I have other strange things happening on Safari. It seems to me that Safari is messing up with margins on Highcharts. I'm thinking that because I do have marginLeft and marginRight set up, but those are clearly ignored.

Here is the screenshot to clarify the issue:

[Left is Chrome, Right is Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEd8a.png)

Thanks,

Comment: Could you tell which Safari version do you use? I tested a demo where I set left margin on Safari v10.11 and it seems everything works fine. Also, provide me with a working JSFiddle demo where this problem occurs.

Comment: The Safari's version is 10.1.12. I'll try to set `textOverflow` and see how it looks like and I'll also provide a JSFiddle

Comment: There's a typo. I meant 10.1.2